# Kleene Closure for infinite subset

Tags: regex, automata, dfa, automata-theory, kleene-star

Let L = {a<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0}, where [image] and [image] for all n >= 1.

Thus L consists of sequences of a of all lengths, including a sequence
of length 0. Let L2 be any infinite subset of L. I need to show there always exists a DFA to recognize (L2)*.

If L2 is a finite subset it is very obvious as L2 would be a DFA and hence by kleene closure L2* would be recognized by a DFA. But I am unable to get it for infinite subset as L2 may not be expressed as DFA for eg length of strings is prime.

Comment: How does this relate to programming, besides it being CS theory? Why is it tagged regex? Is this homework?

Comment: where is programming mentioned?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think general questions about CS theory are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. If you are trying to prove something using a program, however, that would definitely be on-topic. But I'll let someone else decide that.

Comment: @Ranveer can you stop editing this post? You've repeatedly made the question nonsensical.

Comment: Actually this is the final thing. I had a conversation with the OP. I had problems putting latex into the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach

While there exists a DFA to describe a set L of all strings a<sup>n</sup>, n >= 0, there is no guarantee that a DFA exists for all subsets of L. The subset of L which contains all strings whose length is prime, as you have mentioned, is one example where a DFA the describes the language does not exist.

The correct approach would be to directly prove that (L')* is a regular language for any subset L' of L.

### Definition

Let us define GCD(K) = GCD<sub>w ∈ K, |w| > 0</sub> (|w|), where K is any *non-empty* subset of L. We can now refer to the greatest common divisor of all the lengths of all *non-empty* words in a language K as GCD(K). This definition applies for both *finite* and *infinite* subset of L.

Similarly, we can define LCM(K) = LCM<sub>w ∈ K, |w| > 0</sub> (|w|), where K is any *non-empty* **and** *finite* subset of L.

### Proof

We will try to prove that when GCD(L') = 1, there exists a number M such that all string a<sup>n</sup>, n >= M belongs to the language (L')*. This leads to (L')* being a regular language, since we can construct a regular expression of the form:

> All strings of length less than M and belongs to (L')*
>   OR
>   All strings of length more than or equal to M

The regular expression above has a corresponding DFA which has M + 1 states.

When GCD(L') > 1, we can reduce the problem to the case of GCD = 1 by "dividing" all words in the subset L' by GCD(L').

---

If GCD(L') = 1 (set-wise coprime), there exists a finite subset S of L' where GCD of the length of all strings in S is also 1.

> We can prove the claim above by construction.
>
> - Pick any element w<sub>1</sub> from L', |w<sub>1</sub>| > 0 and construct set S<sub>1</sub> = {w<sub>1</sub>}
> - If GCD(S<sub>n</sub>) = 1, S<sub>n</sub> is the set we want to find.
> - If GCD(S<sub>n</sub>) > 1, pick an element w<sub>n+1</sub> from L' and construct set S<sub>n+1</sub> = {w<sub>n+1</sub>} ∪ S<sub>n</sub>, so that
>     GCD(S<sub>n+1</sub>) < GCD(S<sub>n</sub>)
>
> If GCD(S<sub>n</sub>) > 1, there always exists an element from set L' that decreases the GCD when we add it to the set; otherwise, the GCD of the set L' cannot be 1. And since the length of the first element w<sub>1</sub> has finite number of factors, the size of the final set S is finite.

Back to the problem, for any subset L' of L, we can find a *finite* subset S of L', which satisfies GCD(L') = GCD(S). From the set S, we can construct a generalized linear Diophantine equation with |S| unknowns a<sub>i</sub>:

> a<sub>1</sub>|w<sub>1</sub>| + a<sub>2</sub>|w<sub>2</sub>| + ... + a<sub>|S|</sub>|w<sub>|S|</sub>| = c where c is a non-negative integer

Since GCD(S) = 1, the equation above is [always solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/how-to-find-an-integer-solution-for-general-diophantine-equation-ax-by-cz), by recursively applying the solution to the simplest form of linear Diophantine equation ax + by = c.

Solve the generalized Diophantine equations above for c = 0 to (LCM(S) - 1). The solutions (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>|S|</sub>) can contain negative numbers. However, we can keep adding multiples of LCM(S) to both sides of the equations until all the solutions contain only non-negative numbers.

Let k be the smallest multiple of LCM(S) so that all Diophantine equations for c = k * LCM(S) + q, q = 0 to (LCM(S) - 1) has non-negative solution. Then we can define M as k * LCM(S), since any strings whose length larger than M can be decomposed as concatenation of words in S (thus in L').

### Example calculation based on the proof

Suppose L' is set of all strings in L whose length is prime.

Let us construct set S = {a<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>5</sup>}. S can be {a<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>19</sup>} or {a<sup>5</sup>, a<sup>23</sup>}, doesn't really matter. The final value of M might be different, but it doesn't affect the fact that (L')* is regular language.

We need to solve 10 equations (separately):

2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 0 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (0, 0)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 1 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (3, -1)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 2 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (1, 0)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 3 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (-1, 1)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 4 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (2, 0)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 5 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (0, 1)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 6 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (3, 0)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 7 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (1, 1)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 8 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (4, 0)
2a<sub>1</sub> + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 9 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (2, 1)

Add one LCM(2,5) = 10. Note that we can modify the solution directly without solving again, due to the property of LCM:

2a<sub>1</sub> + (5a<sub>2</sub> + 10) = 1 + 10 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (3, 1)
(2a<sub>1</sub> + 10) + 5a<sub>2</sub> = 3 + 10 => (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) = (4, 1)

Since all the solutions are non-negative, and we only add one LCM(2,5), M = 10.

The regular expression for (L')* can be constructed:

a<sup>2</sup>+a<sup>4</sup>+a<sup>5</sup>+a<sup>6</sup>+a<sup>7</sup>+a<sup>8</sup>+a<sup>9</sup>+a<sup>10</sup>a*

The regular expression is not very compact, but it is not our concern here. For the sake of the proof, we only need to know there exists a number M so that a<sup>n</sup> belongs to (L')* for all n >= M, which implies that there are finite number of states and a DFA can be constructed.